# xdotool: command to resize current active firefox window?

Tags: xdotool

I have multiple firefox windows, I'd like to use a shortcut of current window manager to resize curent active firefox's window to specific size and position.

How xdotool command to achieve this?

EDIT: For example I have window manager named `dwm` and I map some shortcuts of this window manager, then I can press a combined keys on the current firefox's window.

Focus still on the firefox'window.

Probably we can map to call a shell script with combined key.

Comment: please explain what 'current active' means. is that the firefox window that has the keyboard focus? in that case typing the `xdotool` command in a terminal would not work, because it's the terminal which has the focus. If you want to resize all firefox windows: `xdotool search --classname Navigator windowsize %@ 800 600`; replace `%@` with `%1` to resize just the first from the list.

Comment: I've just updated the question. Yes, current firefox windows = focus on firefox windows, not terminal.

Comment: then the first part of my answer should just work. please comment on it if it does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to resize the firefox window that has the keyboard focus:

```
#! /bin/sh
fw=`xdotool getwindowfocus`
for nw in `xdotool search --classname Navigator`; do
   test "$fw" = "$nw" && xdotool windowsize "$fw" 800 600
done
```

Notice that this will not work if you're typing the script in a terminal; in that case it's the terminal that has the focus. You can use `getactivewindow` instead of `getwindowfocus` if your window manager supports `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`.

If instead you want to resize the top-first firefox window:

```
nw=`xdotool search --classname Navigator | tail -1`
test "$nw" && xdotool windowsize "$nw" 800 600
```

**Note**

If you're using `dwm`, then please consider this (from the dwm's [homepage](https://dwm.suckless.org/)):

> dwm is customized through editing its source code, which makes it
>   extremely fast and secure - **it does not process any input data which
>   isn’t known at compile time**, except window titles and status text read
>   from the root window’s name. You don’t have to learn Lua/sh/ruby or
>   some weird configuration file format (like X resource files), beside
>   C, to customize it for your needs: you only have to learn C (at least
>   in order to edit the header file).
>
> Because dwm is customized through
>   editing its source code, it’s pointless to make binary packages of it.
>   This keeps its userbase small and elitist. No novices asking stupid
>   questions.

This means that calling an external script is simply not going to work.
You're supposed to resize windows, check their class, etc from `C`, by modifying `dwm`'s source code.

Comment: I use `tmuxvm`, how would it apply to this case?

Comment: I don't know, it's the first time I hear about it.

Comment: I'll do some hacks into the wm. Your script should work then as I tried to call a script already.